# Running two Streamlit functions at the same time

Tags: python, streamlit

Im creating a stock prediction app in streamlit. I am trying to run two functions, main() and progress_bar() at the same time. I looked around for a bit and found that I can use threading.

I tried this, but got the error:
`2023-06-30 05:39:33.852 Thread 'Thread-10': missing ScriptRunContext`

Heres the 2 functions i want to run at the same time:

```
def progress_bar(epochs):
    print("Progress bar started")
    progress_bar = st.empty()
    progress_text = st.empty()
    progress_value = st.empty()

    progress = []
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        progress.append(epoch)
        progress_bar.progress(epoch + 1)
        progress_value.text(f"Progress: {int((epoch + 1) / epochs * 100)}%")

        time.sleep(1.05)  # Simulating training progress

def main():
    st.write("Enter a stock symbol and press 'Predict' to get the predicted next month open prices.")

    stock_symbol = st.text_input("Stock Symbol", value="")
    if st.button("Predict"):
        print("Predicting...")
        ds_scaled, normalizer = load_data(stock_symbol)
        model, ds_test = train_model(ds_scaled, normalizer)
        lst_output = generate_predictions(model, ds_test, normalizer)
        ds_new = ds_scaled.tolist()
        ds_new.extend(lst_output)
        final_graph = normalizer.inverse_transform(ds_new).tolist()
        plot_stock_prediction(final_graph, stock_symbol)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainThread = threading.Thread(target=main).start()
    progressThread = threading.Thread(target=progress_bar).start()
```

Can anyone help?